# Automatic login doesn't work while prompt does

Tags: asp.net, iis, internet-explorer-8, windows-authentication

I have a local ASP.NET web application that I use in IE. Some time ago I began experiencing problems with automatic login on to it. When I set "prompt for username and password" in Security settings - it's all fine, but when I set "automatic login only in intranet zone" - all I get is a screen "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". I think it should at least ask for username and password when login fails, but this is all it gives. I don't know what could cause this - don't remember doing anything special, I just used manual login for some time, and then wanted to go back to automatic.

The same application works with automatic login fine on other computers, both when using locally and from my machine also. So I assume there is not IE issue and not application issue - maybe something with IIS configuration? But I can't find anything appropriate there.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I just found out that the same error is whith "http://localhost". But I have another web application that works (don't know about how it is authenticated though).

Answer (score 0):

Is the site you are trying to access in the same domain as your machine?  Or rather, is the domain extension of the site the same as your box and/or registered in IE?

The option "send on intranet" only sends to domains that are setup  in the Sites menu of IE's security option, and they can be deceptive.  Sometimes it won't have registered a domain you would assume it thinks is local.

In IE, thats in Tools/Options -> Security -> select Intranet -> hit Sites -> select advanced -> check the list.

If that all looks ok, I would first determine to see if IE is truly sending the NTLM token.  Use an HTTP monitor like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or Firebug to check the request headers.  You should see one  for

```
Authorization: Negotiate
```

This is the NTLM token sent in response to a 401 "Prompt for auth" response on the intial hit.  If this isn't being sent, IE doesn't think it should pass the user/pass.  If it is, then you may want to double check your web server's logs to see who it thinks you are. AT least this would help you know for sure which "side" the problem is on.

Comment: Thank you, Taylor, but finally I ended up reinstalling IIS (after seeing the same error opening ISS home page I thought that there is realy something wrong). And (after some aspnet_regiis staff) it began to work!